# Why did the C++ std library have a binary search tree well before a hashmap which is in many ways simpler

Tags: c++, algorithms, data-structures

Looking at the two data structures and algorithms to handle them, a hashmap is not really any more complicated than a binary search tree and possibly less complicated.  And the hashmap has the advantage of constant time access of a key.  So why did we get a std::map very early on in the history of the standard library but for std::unordered_map which is a hashmap we had to wait for C++11 ?

Comment: For historical and sociological reasons. The standardization committee had to meet many times to agree on something.

Comment: I meant "social" reasons, not sociological.

Comment: No there's real differences in how the memory allocation can be performed in each.

Comment: @FrankHileman I don't understand your comment???

Comment: @user619818 My comment was not a good one. I was referring to the differences between the structures, not the timing of their introduction. Generally speaking, a binary tree can allocate and free nodes individually or in small chunks, whereas hash tables are most simply implemented by allocating a contiguous vector or array. The amortization of the hash table copying cost is usually done by doubling the size of this array each time the hashtable runs out of space. Therefore in some situations a binary tree is superior.

Comment: One of the things I've noticed is that linked structures were a lot more popular in the 80s and 90s, and I certainly felt more comfortable using them back them. I don't know why exactly; if they were always inefficient and we just didn't know so well, or if the memory hierarchy has skewed more in performance since then. Unfortunately I wasn't so into computer architecture back then and didn't have internet and so forth, but back then linked structures were a lot more popular and seemed to be considered much better than they are today.

Comment: If feels like the hardware has skewed in performance in terms of the memory hierarchy since then, like maybe cache misses have gotten more expensive or something, or the cache lines have gotten bigger (maybe it's now more wasteful to just load a single node into one and not use anything else with 64-byte cache lines, if they were smaller historically). There wasn't so much talk about CPU cache back then as far as I knew (though my memory is all a blur and I wasn't paying so much attention back then to these types of things).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing a hashmap is much more complicated, not in actual implementation but in the possible variants you have to pick from:

- open addressing vs. separate chaining,

  - whether the nodes in separate chaining holds one or more items,
- the hash function,
- growth factor,
- whether to keep key and value together,

All of those affect performance in a way where it's not easy to say which one is better *in general*.

Compared to that the red-black tree is much simpler to create a prototype for that people won't bikeshed endlessly about.

Comment: I think the *prototype* isn’t so much the issue. The issue is that the implementation is a black box and can be left unspecified. As you allude to, the *interface* to a comparison-based map is dead simple. How you implement it … who cares? Go wild. Balanced binary tree? Skip list? You got it. Whereas a hash table has *lots* of moving parts in its interface that needs to be configured/standardised, and which might turn out to be badly specified in the future. [Things like open addressing don’t *appear* to impact the interface of a hash table but they do introduce leaky abstractions]

Comment: Also, the properties of a hash-map are extraordinarily hard to prove, depending greatly on the quality of your hash function.  O(n) behavior for lookups looks pretty bad unless you can have confidence that your hash function is good enough that you won't hit that case often.  For a risk-averse standards community, that could be quite the limitation.

Answer (score 4):

From http://marknelson.us/2011/09/03/hash-functions-for-c-unordered-containers/,

> It’s a little bit of an embarrassment to the C++ community that it didn’t have a hash table in the standard library until TR1 was published in 2005. In a perfect world the original standard should have contained hash map and hash set containers. But Alexander Stepanov didn’t include these containers in the original Standard Template Library, and the standardization committee was reluctant to bless containers that didn’t have a decent amount of mileage in the real world.

Standards committees are generally reactive rather than proactive. C was created in 1969 but wasn't standardized until 1989, and C++ was created in 1979 but wasn't standardized until 1998. The C++ committee took some proactive actions in the original version of the C++ standard, some of which turned out to be mistakes. (There were essentially no fully compliant compilers for the original version of the standard.) The 2003 update was primarily a bug fix. The committee was not about to take any proactive actions in 2003 for functionality that hadn't been tested in the field by multiple compiler vendors.

That said, if you were willing to work with functionality that officially wasn't part of the standard but that were blessed as becoming a part of the standard in the future, you had access to an unordered map well before 2011.

Answer (score 1):

From a viewpoint of specification and standardization, a hash table is quite a bit more complex than a tree.

For the tree-based (ordered) containers, the standard only needs to specify that to store an object, you must be able to assign, copy, and compare it<sup>1</sup>. All of those are already pretty well-defined concepts, and most built-in types satisfy them (the only obvious exception being floating point NaN's, which don't satisfy a strict weak ordering).

For hashing, you need to specify (at least) some way of hashing types. That, in turn, required more infrastructure, as as `std::hash`, with specializations for all the built-in types. In the case of `std::unordered_*`, it also means quite a bit of extra specification around iterators, adding the iterators local to a bucket to the normal iterators used for everything else.

---

<sup>1. yes, it goes into a *little* more detail, such as requiring that the comparison satisfy a strict weak ordering, but that's pretty simple too.</sup>